# balanced parenthesis Leetcode - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

I took a different approach to solve this problem. Most common way to solve this is by using stacks. I took an approach where I count the open parenthesis "(" and then count close parenthesis ")", if the numbers don't match the code will return false.

When I run this code it returns false every time. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my current code:

```
    class Solution:
        def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
            if len(s)%2 != 0:
                print('false')
                
                
            open_b = s.count("[")
            open_p = s.count("(")
            open_cb = s.count("{")
    
            close_b = s.count("]")
            close_p = s.count(")")
            close_cb = s.count("}")
            if open_b != close_b and open_p != close_p and open_cb != close_cb:
                print('false') 
    
            else:
                print('true')
```

Here is the actual question:

> Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
>
> An input string is valid if:
>
> - Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
> - Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Example 1:

```
Input: s = "()"
Output: true
```

Comment: Your program will also print `True` for the case `])}{([`, which should be incorrect too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first problem to your question

> when I run this code it returns false every time. What am I doing wrong?

Your logic for the if-clause is wrong, since you are using

`if open_b != close_b and open_p != close_p and open_cb != close_cb:`

to translate that into English, it means to execute the true-clause when all of conditions are true, that is ***none of the bracket has to match***.

In a case `open_b == close_b` while `open_p != close_p` and `open_cb != close_cb`, it will not execute the true-clause, but the false-clause, which in your case `print('true')`.

To fix it, you can simply replace `and` with `or`, i.e.

`if open_b != close_b or open_p != close_p or open_cb != close_cb:`

**HOWEVER, fixing this issue does not mean your script is correct, since the algorithm it uses is fundamentally uncapable to handle cases that has the same number of matches but incorrect ordering, such as `])}{([`. Therefore, you still need to come up with a different solution.**

Answer (score 1):

- We have to write a for loop first:
- Here is a solution using stack, commonly used for that:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, base_string):
        memo = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']': '['}
        stack = [0]
        for character in base_string:
            if character in memo:
                if stack.pop() != memo[character]:
                    return False
            else:
                stack.append(character)
        return stack == [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I run this code it returns false every time. What am I doing wrong?

Actually, your code doesn't return *anything* explicitly, which means it will implicitly return `None`, which is indeed considered *falsey* in a boolean context.

So, since you never return anything, you *always* implicitly return `None`.